# Adding a mask to a jeditable field

Tags: javascript, jeditable

I have been trying to put a date mask on a jEditable field but can't get it to work. It would be fantastic if someone could explain how!

To make the field editable I added the following to my .aspx page:

```
<script src="<%:Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-1.4.4.min.js")%>" type="text/javascript">
</script>
<script src="<%:Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.jeditable.js")%>" type="text/javascript">
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {

        $('.editable').editable('<%=Url.Action("UpdateSettings") %>', {
            type: 'text',
            cancel: 'Cancel',
            event: 'dblclick',
            submit: 'OK',
            tooltip: 'double Click to edit...'
        });
    });
</script>
```

How do I modify this to make the field date masked?

Comment: sorry but what do you mean by a date mask? do you mean you wan to see the date if nothing is entered?

Comment: @user666262 - did any of the answers help? Please +1 answers you like, and tick the one that best answered, if any.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(".masked").editable("http://www.appelsiini.net/projects/jeditable/php/save.php", { 
        indicator : "<img src='img/indicator.gif'>",
        type      : "masked",
        mask      : "99/99/9999",
        submit    : 'OK',
        tooltip   : "Click to edit..."
    });
```

Comment: Hi odle! Is there any way to get notified if the input mask is complete? I want my input to focus on the next as soon the mast text is complete, like as I finish typing "11/12/2014" in above masked input, then it the focus should move to next input. can you point me  somewhere in this regard? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by making use of Masked Input:
http://digitalbush.com/projects/masked-input-plugin/

Check out http://www.appelsiini.net/projects/jeditable/custom.html where Mika (Jeditable) has provided a sample of its usage.